# How to import Maven libraries with SBT?

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

I would like to import Maven libraries either with the Maven's XML file or SBT's Scala file. I guess there already are the same questions out, but I could't quite find any. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just treat remote Maven repositories normally. Unless you want to utilize your local .m2/repository. See below for an example `Build.scala` using both:

```
object myBuild extends Build {
  lazy val mainProject = Project(
    id="root",
    base=file("."),
    settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
      name := "Root project",
      scalaVersion := "2.11.4",
      version := "0.1",
      resolvers ++= Seq(remoteMavenRepo, localMavenRepo),
      libraryDependencies ++= List(
        mavenLibrary1, mavenLibrary2
      )
    )
  )

  val remoteMavenRepo = "Sonatype Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
  val localMavenRepo = "Local Maven" at Path.userHome.asFile.toURI.toURL + ".m2/repository"

  // if library folows scala version suffix convention, then we use %%
  val mavenLibrary1 = "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.0.2"

  // if it's a java library with no scala version suffix, then we use %
  val mavenLibrary2 = "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.4"
```

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that `resolvers` already includes some repos by default - in particular, Maven Central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/).